# Why i got this error while uploading my appbundle to play store?

Tags: flutter, google-play, apk, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

"This release does not add or remove any application packages."

I am getting the error above when i try to upload my app to google play store. Does anyone have any solution?

I try to upload app on google play store but got this error
"This release does not add or remove any application packages."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you incremented your build number in you pubspec.yaml, e. g. 1.0.0+1 to 1.0.0+2?